# Cross Validate and Get Precision, Recall, F-Score for Each Class Label

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Is there a scikit learn function which can perform cross validation on my dataset and output not just the overall, precision, recall and f-score but all the precision, recall and f-score for each class label.

Comment: Which estimator are you using for your model?

Answer (score 0):

These two links may something you are looking for.
[Confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) &  [f1_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)